# Find all occurrences of a specific value in an array in a jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, json

So, my goal is the get the count of all times when a value appears in a column.

I have a table (**my_table**) with a jsob type column **result**. The value in the column looks something like this:

```json
[
 {
    "id": "b28a6f8c-b504-4623-a033-ea74d258d76f",
    "code": "S0255"

},
{
    "id": "773c571b-db7a-4219-a003-36a89dcc5cb9",
    "code": "T02816"
},
{
    "id": "ddfdb739-46f3-4640-a119-34a283ce81df",
    "code": "S0255"

}
]
```

**The result should be : count = 2**

This is an array of objects, hence the confusion(Is there an alternate query I can use to test?

My current query is this :

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) as codeCount
         FROM my_table
         CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(result) as res
         WHERE res ->> 'code' = 'S0255'
         AND result != JSONB '[]'
```

I am getting the following error :

> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [22023]: ERROR:
> cannot extract elements from an object

How do I resolve this? Also is there a different way to achieve this?

Edit: after some more research I research I found the column contained both array and plain object values, I just added one more filter and it runs fine now.

```
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) as codeCount
         FROM my_table
        CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(result) as res
         WHERE res ->> 'code' = 'S0255'
         AND result != JSONB '[]'
         and  jsonb_typeof(result) = 'array'
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! What happens if you run your query on a `psql` or `pgAgdmin` client?

Comment: I'm currently using Dbeaver

Comment: I know - that' a Java client. I want (ideally) to know what error you obtain using the native one or, failing that, `pgAdmin`?

Comment: Is there a different way to achieve this irrespective of the client?

Comment: You could only have got that error if your JSON was an object, not an array. Compare this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8a92d2085892e7a00e3952394cf8b949 and this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0a3e138541e97d3cec9d7b6967e660d9 What is your *real* JSON?

Comment: It's an array of objects for sure. Is there another way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get this error is if there is some row in `my_table` that is *not* a JSON array. Find the offending rows with

```
SELECT id
FROM my_table
WHERE jsonb_typeof(result) <> 'array';
```

Comment: Ok, I ran this query and there are both arrays and just plain objects stored in the column.

Comment: Then the mystery is solved, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how many elements the array has with a specific `code` value.

In that case a JSON path query might be easier to deal with as it is more lenient about the structure:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(result, '$[*] ? (@.code == "S0255").id')
from my_table;
```

With your sample data, this returns `["b28a6f8c-b504-4623-a033-ea74d258d76f", "ddfdb739-46f3-4640-a119-34a283ce81df"]`. If the `result` column contains something that is not an array (or array elements that don't have a `code` key), then the result is an empty array.

To get the number of elements from that array you can use:

```
jsonb_array_length(jsonb_path_query_array(result, '$[*] ? (@.code == "S0255").id'))
```

The major difference to your query is that this won't apply a `DISTINCT` on the IDs that are returned. If you really do need the distinct, you can unnest the result array from the JSON path:

```
select count(distinct id)
from my_table
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array(result, '$[*] ? (@.code == "S0255").id')) as res(id)
where result @> '[{"code": "S0255"}]'
```